# Show failure link in 404 error custom page

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, custom-pages

Is it possible to show the user the link or the file, which can not be found through the html code of a 404 error custompage?

I asked google, but could not found any informations.

Also I do not know php and would now wondering 
if it would be possible only with htaccess and html?

If not, what could I do with php, while using the htaccess redirect?
There are any simple ways?

My htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /funktion.fehler.php
```

Comment: What's your htaccess redirect look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the error document:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /funktion.fehler.php
```

Then you can use a couple of php variables. Something like:

```
print('The URL ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ' does not exist');
```

You can also use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`.